# Generate a circle randomly on the screen and make it green or red

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas

So ive been trying to make a game app that either displays a red button with text or a green button with text randomly on the android screen. If anyone can help me with this i would appreciate it. also on a side note i want to slowly generate faster cool upside if anyone knows how to do that. Thanks!

```
@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    String str = "Joke of the day";
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    paint = new Paint();
    Random random = new Random();
    Random randomTwo = new Random();

    //Rect ourRect = new Rect();
    Rect topRect = new Rect();
    Rect backGround = new Rect();

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    backGround.set(0,0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight());
    canvas.drawRect(backGround, paint);
    for(int i = 0; i <= 900; i++;){

    }

    if(blank == time){
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(random, randomTwo, 230, paint);
    }else {
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawCircle(random, randomTwo, 230, paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `Random` instance.

Declare `private long lastUpdated = 0;` and `private int lastColor = Color.BLACK;` outside of the onDraw.

Update the bottom portion to:

```
final float radius = 230f;
if(System.currentTimeMillis() > lastUpdated + 1000){
    lastColor = random.nextInt(2) == 1 ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN;
    lastUpdated = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
paint.setColor(lastColor);
canvas.drawCircle(random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-radius/2) + radius/2f, random.nextInt(canvas.getHeight()-radius/2) + radius/2f, radius, paint);
```

This will draw a circle of either red or green at random location every second.

You need the radius/2 because the coordinates are from the center of the circle.

As for your second part of your question, *also on a side note i want to slowly generate faster cool upside*. You'd have to clarify what you mean.

Edit:
Provided a more complete (and correct) sample here:
https://gist.github.com/mshi/8287fd3956c9a917440d

Comment: i haven't initalized the variables blank and time. I dont know what i need to compare there or how to even set the time for it.

Comment: You want to continuously display random circles or only when an event occurs?

Comment: and i want it to randomly generate the color of the circle as well so that will go into blank

Comment: You need to clarify more, or give examples.
For example, the screen will have a 2 different colored circles on the screen every second? Or do they change after some user action?

Comment: oh ya i just want like 1 per 1 second or 1000 nano

Comment: the time variable will be 1000 nano seconds but im not sure what the blank variable should be

Comment: sorry i am still very knew to this its hard to gather a grasp to some of programming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74050/discussion-between-devin-tripp-and-michael-shi).