# Im trying to draw either a green or a red circle forever on to the android screen

Tags: java, android, random, android-canvas

im trying to make a game that when a user clicks on a green button it disappears but when a user clicks on a red button they loose im having trouble displaying multiple random buttons continuously on forever onto the screen here is my code

```
package com.Tripps.thesimplegame;

import java.util.Random;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Paint.FontMetrics;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawingView extends View {
    int mBackgroundColor = 000000;
    String yo = "#";
    Paint paint;
    final float radius = 230f;
    private long lastUpdated = 0;
    private int lastColor = Color.BLACK;

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

        String str = "Joke of the day";
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint = new Paint();
        Random random = new Random();
        Random randomTwo = new Random();

        //Rect ourRect = new Rect();
        Rect topRect = new Rect();
        Rect backGround = new Rect();

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        backGround.set(0,0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight());
        canvas.drawRect(backGround, paint);


        while(System.currentTimeMillis() > lastUpdated + 1000){
            lastColor = random.nextInt(2) == 1 ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN;
            lastUpdated = System.currentTimeMillis();
            paint.setColor(lastColor);
            canvas.drawCircle(random.nextInt((int) (canvas.getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f, random.nextInt((int) (canvas.getHeight()-radius/2)) + radius/2f, radius, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see the gist in the updated answer of http://stackoverflow.com/a/29332485/4726782 
I also pasted it in our discussions link.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is happening now, nd what would you like to be different?

Anyways I recommend doing some things for performance and readability reasons:

- make two `static int` variables, CANVAS_WIDTH and CANVAS_HEIGHT, initialize them in `onCreate`, and use them in `onDraw` instead of querying them every time.
- for the background, you don't need to always draw a rect as big as the screen. Just give your DrawView a black background in the xml.
- why use `while`? It's gonna get executed only once anyway, so how about using `if`?

After writing this, I have something that might just be your solution.

First, make a `Handler animationHandler` and initialize it in onCreate.

Make a

```
Runnable r = new Runnable{
    run(){
        invalidate();
    }
};
```

and make the last statement in onDraw `animationHandler.posteDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);`

Also make a `public static final int FRAME_RATE = 30` for 30 fps or = 15 for 60 fps.

Now you can make another `public static final int SECOND`, which practically tells you, how often you need to run it until one second is over, so initilize with `1000/FRAME_RATE`.

Make another variable, timer, initialized with 0, and put timer++; in your onDraw.

Now put that in onDraw:

```
if(timer>=SECOND){
    //draw your circle here
    timer=0;
}
```

Now you just gotta ask if the user touched a circle. THat is another kinda big thing, and I might do that one after I've eaten, although I recommend you do it yourself, it's not too hard a task I think.

Comment: it is actually a hard task the why i know how to get when a user has clicked something is through the main onCreate method then i create a Button something = (Button) findViewById(R.id.whateverxmlfile);

Comment: but since im creating a button for the circle its a lot different

Comment: technically im creating a button for the color and that has an int value so instead of the findViewById method i need something else